# How to implement reCaptcha in angularFire 2 Account Create with email?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, angularfire5

I am trying to use angularFire 2 to login and create account in firebase. Phone Login have a reCaptcha field that is working good. Create account with email and password is also working fine but I want to use reCaptcha in create form like Phone Login function but there is no method I found, for create account with email and password in angularFire with reCaptcha verification . I tried docs also but nothing like this. Please help me if there is any option like this or not in angular fire 2.
I am using `"angularfire2": "^4.0.0-rc.1",`